# $location.path in Angular JS is not working

Tags: angularjs

I know this question has been asked many times and after going through the replies and making the changes in my code I am still not able to open a different page by pressing a button. I just started with Angular JS, so can anyone please help me with the same ? 
**(The address in the url changes but the page is not displayed)**

CODE:

---

Index.html

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html  ng-app="testAngularApp" class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <button ng-click="testButton()"> Page Change</button>
      </div>

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

app.js

---

```
'use strict';

/**
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
angular
  .module('testAngularApp', [])
  .config(function($locationProvider){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

---

main.js

---

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name testAngularApp.controller:MainCtrl
 * @description
 * # MainCtrl
 * Controller of the testAngularApp
 */
angular.module('testAngularApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($timeout, $log, $location, $scope) {
    $scope.testButton = function(){

        // Testing the opening of different page.
        $log.info($location.path());
        $timeout(function () {
            $location.path('/views/Dummy.html');
        });

    };
  });
```

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location  Use window.location.href (see "What does it not do").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (The address in the url changes but the page is not displayed)

[$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/%24location) does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed. To reload the page after changing the URL, use the lower-level API, $window.location.href.

```
$window.location.href = '/views/Dummy.html';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please inject ngRoute to your app and don't forged add  and reference to script [angular-route.js](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.19/angular-route.min.js)

```
angular
      .module('testAngularApp', ['ngRoute'])
      .config(function($locationProvider){
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        });
```

and in you controller

```
 $location.path('/path'); <- path has to be defined in your app.config ...(ie .when(/path..)not just path to html file
```

Comment: I tried adding ngRoute as dependency and also in the script, but can't jump to next page ..

Answer (score 0):

Your $timeout has no value for how long it should delay. You need to provide it after the function.

```
    $timeout(function () {
        $location.path('/views/Dummy.html');
    }, 1);
```

Comment: Tried as mentioned above, but same result

Comment: You also don't have an ng-view in your base page, so there is nowhere for that view to be loaded. Without a route and ng-view, you are not going to see the change you are looking for.

Comment: I want to open a new page, not show the changes in the same page. Can't I open a new page using $location.path ?

Comment: Opening a new page will exit your app. Angular is made to create and run a Single-Page App (SPA). You do that by changing the views.